# Numerous delegate events on a page

Tags: asp.net, delegates

Bit of a noob question.

I am developing a web page that has a structure of master page => aspx => userconcontrol => nested usercontrol.

There are numerous events that can happen on a page, I could bookmark an item from the masterpage down, the usercontrol up, I could page data etc.

I have used delegates to navigate between usercontrols and page, however I have a question.

What happens when a user hits several bookmarks and then pages the data? Are events queued and processed - is it managed by the system - is there something I should be doing?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'Bookmark'?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to allow the user to Bookmark the page? The user goes to page X and then advances a pageable control control and then attempts to Bookmark the page both Bookmarks return the user to the same page X...

If you are attempting to maintain the state of the second example via a book mark, you will need to render you state date in the query string. `mypage.aspx` (the first example) vs. `mypage.aspx?start=25` (the second example).

An easy approach to this is to capture the paging events in your control and instead of rendering an update there, use Response.Redirect() back to the same page and pass an updated query string with the state change. The page then renders the control based on the query string values.